# Filter WhereSelectEnumerableIterator of Generic List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which builds a Generic List of Abc from a database query.

```
List<Abc> lAbc = DB.GetAbc();

var lRawData = from r in lAbc
               group r by r.Stage1Check into s
               select s.ToList();
```

This gives me a WhereSelectEnumerableIterator of Generic List of Abc - which is ok.  I then write this data to an Excel sheet.

The problem is that I need to further filter this data.  The object Abc contains a property called FilterProp which is a boolean.  What I can't figure out is how to use Linq to filter lRawData where the FilterProp is true?

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
var lRawData = from r in lAbc
               group r by r.Stage1Check into s
               select s.Where(f=>f.FilterProp).ToList();
```

this filter lAbc after grouping.

Comment: Thanks rob - ended up with this var lRawData = from r in lAbc
                            select r.Where(f => f.FilterProp).GroupBy(g => g.Stage1Check).ToList().  The group r by r.Stage1Check into s wouldn't compile.